# how to put the image on top using CSS grid in mobile view

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can do so that image is on top in mobile view? I'm using a CSS grid I'm not yet fully familiar with. my media queries are not showing the output that wanted especially when I'm starting to scale down the screen size the layout is breaking?!

I want to achieve this [mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIi9f.jpg)

```css
   * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 1.5em;
  }

  .container {
    background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 1080px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
  }

  .description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 4em;
  }

  .description h1 {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    padding-right: 3em;
  }

  .description p {
    font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-right: 2em;
  }

  span {
    color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  }

  .stats {
    display: flex;

    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 1.9em;
    padding-right: 6em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }

  h3 {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  }

  .stat p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
  }

  .img-box {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .img-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 0;
  }

  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 500px;
      grid-template-rows: 350px 450px;
    }
  }

  .attribution {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .attribution a {
    color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

      <link
        rel="icon"
        type="image/png"
        sizes="32x32"
        href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
      />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
      <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main class="container">
        <div class="description">
          <h1>Get <span>insights</span>  that help your business grow.</h1>
          <p>
            Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
            regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
          </p>
          <div class="stats">
            <div class="stat">
              <h3>10k+</h3>
              <p>companies</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stat">
              <h3>314</h3>
              <p>templates</p>
            </div>
            <div class="stat">
              <h3>12m+</h3>
              <p>queries</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


        <div class="img-box">
          <img src="/images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="people having a meeting">
        </div>
      </main>

      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you can attain it by enclosing them to a separate containers disply: flex them then flex-direction: column-reverse.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the `flexbox` is a better for this problem.
What I would recommend, forst of all, if you can, move your `img-box` to the top of your `container`, then, insted of `display: grid;`, set the display to `flex`, that way you can easily ocntrol the flow of grid elements.

Im not sure what the desired look is for desktop devices, but what you can for example do is the followoing - this horizontally and vertically centeres your `container` content while leaving the image as wide as the `container`

```
.container {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  height: 400px;
  max-width: 1080px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.img-box {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px !important">
    <main class="container">
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/263237/36633897-d3237f2e-19ad-11e8-960a-daaf5ca3088a.png"
          style="width: 100%"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
        <p>
          Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
          regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.
        </p>
        <div class="stats">
          <div class="stat">
            <h3>10k+</h3>
            <p>companies</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stat">
            <h3>314</h3>
            <p>templates</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stat">
            <h3>12m+</h3>
            <p>queries</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <div class="attribution">
      Challenge by
      <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
        >Frontend Mentor</a
      >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```